# JavaScript, Why does function name have no significance in function literals?

Tags: javascript, function, invoke, literals

I had some doubts for function literals

1. Why does the function name in function literals have no significance?
2. Why aren't they important?
3. Why doesn't the function get invoked when we try to call using the function name in case of function literals?

   ```
   var a = function b(){
           //some code
           }
   b(); //Doesn't work
   ```

Why does the name b have no significance but a does?

I am new to JavaScript and a beginner so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `a.name == "b"` certainly has a significance

Answer (score 0):

Name `b` has significance only inside function. Outside you must call function via `a`.

Comment: Ik that, but why! That's my question! Why doesn't b have significance?! I don't get why...

Comment: @MohammedShoaib because it's an expression and does not declare a name, like `var` or `function` does. That's just how it works.

Comment: It is usefull when you declare some anonymous function and this function must have access to its own properties. But how? Named function declarations help you in this case. Example: `var a = function b() { b.prop = 42; }`. Without `b` name properties inaccessible.